# Downloading Real time rainfall data from Data.gov.sg API (json) with Python

Tags: python, json

I would like to download real-time rainfall data from the `Data.gov.sg` API (in `json` format) with Python from weather station `S17` from [this link](https://data.gov.sg/dataset/realtime-weather-readings?resource_id=8bd37e06-cdd7-4ca4-9ad8-5754eb70a33d), but my code is throwing:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Appreciate if anyone could help! Thanks!

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
import json
import datetime as dt
from xlwt import Workbook

start_date = dt.datetime(2018, 8, 14, 00, 00, 00)
end_date = dt.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 00, 00, 00)

total_days = (end_date - start_date).days + 1
neadatasum = []
for day_number in range(total_days):
    for day_time in range(0, 24, 86400):
        current_date = (start_date + dt.timedelta(days = day_number)).date()
        current_time = (start_date + dt.timedelta(hours = day_time)).time()
        url = 'https://api.data.gov.sg/v1/environment/rainfall?date_time=' + str(current_date) + 'T' + \
              str(current_time)
        headers = {"api-key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
        data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
        actualtime = str(current_date) + 'T' + str(current_time) + '+08:00'
        print(current_date, current_time)
        if not data['items'][0]:
            station_id = 'S71'
            value = 'Nan'
            neadatasum1 = [current_date, current_time, value]
            neadatasum.append(neadatasum1)
        else:
            datatime = data['items'][0]['timestamp']
            if actualtime != datatime:
                station_id = 'S71'
                value = 'Nan'
                neadatasum1 = [current_date, current_time, value]
                neadatasum.append(neadatasum1)
            else:
                station_id = 'S71'
                value = data['items'][0]['timestamp']['readings']['station_id', 'value']
                neadatasum1 = [current_date, current_time, value]
                neadatasum.append(neadatasum1)
print(neadatasum)

wb = Workbook()
sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Rainfall 5 minutes(mm)')
sheet1.write(0, 0, 'Date')
sheet1.write(0, 1, 'Time')
sheet1.write(0, 2, 'Rainfall')

for i, j in enumerate(neadatasum):
    for k, l in enumerate(j):
        sheet1.write(i+1, k, l)

wb.save('Rainfall 5 minutes(mm)(14082018 to 19082018).xls')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/erilpm/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Rainfall.py", line 36, in 
>       value = data['items'][0]['timestamp']['readings']['station_id', 'value']
>   TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Please format your code and add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: I recommend you to hide the API key from your question

Comment: I have added the full error below. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please let me know if my answer does not solve your problem, in which case I'll edit it to try and resolve whatever remains to be resolved :) .  Otherwise, if it does solve the problem, you can click the green check-mark to indicate that it is correct.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if I understand what it is you want this code to do, but I am giving this my best shot.  Please comment if I misunderstood your question!

OK, so first of all, you can't index in

```
data['items'][0]['timestamp']['readings']['station_id', 'value']
```

... if your `data` doesn't look like

```
data[ items , ..., ... ]
        ^
     [ 0, 1, ... ]
       ^
     [..., timestamp, ... ]
             ^
          [readings, ..., ...]
             ^
          [ (station_id, value), (...,...), ..., ... ]
```

... and indeed, that isn't really what your `data` seems to look like.  In fact if I do `print(data['items'][0].keys())`, all I get back are `['timestamp','readings']`.

Note that when I print `data['items']` I get:

> [{'timestamp': '2018-08-14T00:00:00+08:00', 'readings': [{'station_id': 'S77', 'value': 0}, {'station_id': 'S109', 'value': 0}, {'station_id': 'S117', 'value': 0}, {'station_id': 'S55', 'value': 0}, {'station_id': 'S64', 'value': 0}, {'station_id': 'S90', 'value': 0}, etc etc etc

Ok, so I think you want a list of things like `(current time, current date, some value recorded at that specific station)`.  The problem is you're looking at a list of values, not all of them from the station you want ... not just one value.  So, here is my proposal.  Replace everything in the end of your loop with the following:

```
# ok, so you like station S71, right?
station_id = 'S71'
# use list comprehension to get only values from that station
values = [a['value'] for a in data['items'][0]['readings'] if a['station_id'] == station_id]
# iterate over all the matching values
for value in values:
    # and add them to your nifty list!
    neadatasum1 = [current_date, current_time, value]
    neadatasum.append(neadatasum1)
```

I hope this makes sense!  If this does not work, or does not answer your question, or if I misunderstood your question, please comment accordingly and I (or someone more talented) will try and fix this or otherwise answer whatever remains to be answered :)

Comment: I just added in the code values = [a['value'] for a in data['items'][0]['readings'] if a['station_id'] == station_id]  but more errors arise. I think my code has problem because i tried to modify the original code which downloaded 1 hour data to 5 minutes interval.

Comment: You have to also do the whole `for value in values:` loop.  Copy and paste the entire code block starting with `station_id`.  It's not just a one-liner.